# Control volume and brightness use GestureDetector in android

Tags: android, volume, gesturedetector, screen-brightness

As title, I am created a player, and i want change volume and brightness by way use GestureDetector as Mx Player application. (swipe left bottom <-> top to change brightness and swipe right bottom <-> top to change volume )

[image: change volume]

[image: change brightness]

Please help me.

Thanks very much :-)

Comment: use `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener#onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)` then

Comment: Can you help me write more detail ?

Comment: http://www.google.com/m?q=gesturedetector+example&client=ms-opera-mini-android&channel=new

Comment: i'm tried but can't done.
Can you help me create a example or send to me any tutorial detail link ?
Thanks you very much.

Comment: What link have you tried?

Comment: [link](http://www.androidsnippets.com/gesturedetector-and-gesturedetectorongesturelistener)
and some other link...  
I don't know how to can handle manipulation scroll left - right - up - down and distance which it move to set value for brightness, volume. 
I want set brightness when scroll up/down at left half and set volume when scroll up/down at right half like MX Player application.

Comment: The link you tried has onScroll implemented,  try its parameters

Comment: You can try this library. https://github.com/mdg-iitr/Swipper